# How to send Outbound SMS Triggered Send from AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

I need to send out SMS from Email using AMPScript. I already found a link where SMS can be triggered [from automation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211024/sending-sms-with-ampscript-is-it-possible).

Basically, I need to know if I can trigger SMS by just using AMPScript & NOT SSJS?

For triggered emails, I can send emails just using AMPScript & invoking Triggered Send. So, on the similar lines, can I do the same for triggering SMS?